# Onclick event on html calendar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been making a simple scheduler using html,css and js. I've not made any tables using the table tags in html but I've made the table using div tags and css. Now I want to add and onclick function on one of the cells that appear on the table. Can someone help make that function cause every time I try, a cell suddenly disappears upon refresh. Here's the source code to the calendar that I've made.

```
<div id="calendar">
        <ul class="weekdays">
            <div id="course">BIT</div>
            <li>Time</li>
            <li>Sunday</li>
            <li>Monday</li>
            <li>Tuesday</li>
            <li>Wednesday</li>
            <li>Thursday</li>
            <li>Friday</li>
            <li>Saturday</li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="days">
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date">8AM</div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
                <div class="event">
                    <div class="event-desc">

                    </div>
                    <div class="event-time">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>

            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
                <div class="event">
                    <div class="event-desc">

                    </div>
                    <div class="event-time">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="days">
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date">9AM</div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
                <div class="event">
                    <div class="event-desc">

                    </div>
                    <div class="event-time">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>

            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="days">
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date">10AM</div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
                <div class="event">
                    <div class="event-desc">

                    </div>
                    <div class="event-time">

                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
                <div class="event">
                    <div class="event-desc">

                    </div>
                    <div class="event-time">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="days">
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date">11AM</div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
                <div class="event">
                    <div class="event-desc">

                    </div>
                    <div class="event-time">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="days">
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date">12PM</div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
                <div class="event">
                    <div class="event-desc">

                    </div>
                    <div class="event-time">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="days">
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date">1PM</div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date other-month"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
                <div class="event">
                    <div class="event-desc">

                    </div>
                    <div class="event-time">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="days">
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date">2PM</div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date other-month"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
                <div class="event">
                    <div class="event-desc">

                    </div>
                    <div class="event-time">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="days">
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date">3PM</div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date other-month"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
                <div class="event">
                    <div class="event-desc">

                    </div>
                    <div class="event-time">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="days">
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date">4PM</div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date other-month"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
                <div class="event">
                    <div class="event-desc">

                    </div>
                    <div class="event-time">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="days">
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date">5PM</div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date other-month"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
                <div class="event">
                    <div class="event-desc">

                    </div>
                    <div class="event-time">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day other-month">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="day">
                <div class="date"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: add ``onClick="someFunction"`` as an attribute to the corresponding cell. You may alternatively use a script and do ``document.querySelector("<Your_CSS_Selector>").addEventListener("click", someFunction)``

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try javascript query selecter and event listener in this case.

```
<script>
  document.querySelector(".date").addEventListener("click", function() {
     // Do what you want to be onClick
     console.log("Done..");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Difference between .on('click') vs .click().better use onclick